# How to use multiple placeholder values with LIKE sql in mysqljs/mysql?

Tags: node-mysql

It's easy to get this to work if there's only one placeholder value. For example:

```
con.query('select * from user where firstname like ?', "%" + firstname + "%", (err, result) => { 
    // do something
});
```

If you have two placeholders, you need to put them in an array, like so:

```
con.query('select * from user where firstname = ? and lastname = ?', ['Joe', 'Bloggs'], (err, result) => { 
    // do something
});
```

How can I convert this query so it will work with `like`? In other words, how can I get this to work:

```
con.query('select * from user where firstname like ? and lastname like ?', myArray, (err, result) => { 
    // do something
});
```

I need to somehow make `myArray` act like `['%Joe%', '%Bloggs%']`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late, but it maybe useful with someone with same question.

You can use something like this

"SELECT * FROM user WHERE firstname LIKE concat('%' , ?, '%') and lastname LIKE concat('%' , ?, '%')"